# Convert Dynamic query to execute bunch of Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi I am stuck writing a dynamic query with the following code:

```
SELECT 'UPDATE ClientReportCancelOrder SET [' + COLUMN_NAME + '] = NULL 
WHERE [' + COLUMN_NAME + '] = '''''
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
WHERE DATA_TYPE IN ('char','nchar','varchar','nvarchar') and TABLE_NAME='ClientReportCancelOrder'
```

Which produces the result below:

```
UPDATE ClientReportCancelOrder SET [RecordType] = NULL   WHERE [RecordType] = ''
UPDATE ClientReportCancelOrder SET [OrderEventTypeCode] = NULL   WHERE [OrderEventTypeCode] = ''
UPDATE ClientReportCancelOrder SET [ActionTypeCode] = NULL   WHERE [ActionTypeCode] = ''
etc.....
```

I need to execute bunch of result query in SQL proc.

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: above query is executing fine..where is the problem????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
DECLARE @qry NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @qry = 
    COALESCE( @qry + ';', '') +
    'UPDATE ClientReportCancelOrder SET [' + COLUMN_NAME + '] = NULL 
    WHERE [' + COLUMN_NAME + '] = ''''' 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
WHERE DATA_TYPE IN ('char','nchar','varchar','nvarchar') and TABLE_NAME='ClientReportCancelOrder'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @qry
```

Comment: Thanks Baga very much.